# How best to approach a situation where a project you've been working on has been given over to someone else?

Tags: management, review

I'm a web developer. For a month or so I worked (on and off) on a project at my work. I completed it and submitted it for code review, as is normal procedure at my work. Code review allows other senior developers to look over the work and make sure you're not releasing any potential bugs.

The person reviewing my work noted a lot of mistakes and 'rejected' the work and handed it over to another developer. Looking through their notes I see that their comments are correct, but most of them are very minor and quick fixes. It doesn't seem that out-of-the ordinary for a code review (most do come back with comments).

I asked the reviewer why they had taken the project from me and their answer was vague, along the lines of "priorities have changed".

I feel quite upset that not only was my project I had devoted a lot of time to had not only been officially 'rejected' on normal and minor code changes, but also that it was given over to someone else. Further more, due to the companies com system other have been made aware of my 'failure'.

I know the reviewer quite well and know they did not do this as a personal grudge against me, but I do think they came on too heavy handed.

First off, am I over-reacting? My pride is hurt definitely, I feel, honestly, pretty down about it having put so many hours and care into and having obviously not earned the trust of the reviewer to fix the mistakes.

How should I handle this situation? Should I approach the reviewer even though they may not like me challenging them?

Comment: @Kilisi How do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just carry on.

Never take things personal, you are doing a job and doing it the best you can. Especially that a month or so is not a lot of time.

So, as long as you are getting the feedback through comments, learn from them and move forward. Put a personal goal for your self, that your bugs, whether small or big, should go to the minimal possible. Then, use the comments/reviews as your metric system to measure your progress.